# set statement_timeout in properties on opening connection

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I want to use the `statement_timeout` connection parameter when I open a connection.

I have successfully tested this parameter via executing `SET statement_timeout to 5000` as statement but I want it to be provided on opening the connection.

Currently I'm having the following methods (simplified):

```
public Connection openConnection() {
    
    try {
      Driver driver = (Driver) Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver").newInstance();
      return driver.connect("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:15432/postgres", getProperties());
    } catch (Exception exp) {
      throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Unable to connect to JDBC with additional connection properties.", exp);
    }
  }

private Properties getProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("statement_timeout", "5000");
    return properties;
  }
```

But even when querying `SELECT pg_sleep(6)` (This query will take at least 6000ms) no exception occurs.

Is it even possible? Because on [Chapter 3. Initializing the Driver](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html) I only found three other timeouts: `loginTimeout`, `connectTimeout`, `socketTimeout`. Are they related somehow to mine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html#connection-parameters), you should use the `options` parameter:

> - **options** = String
>
> Specify 'options' connection initialization parameter.
>
> The value of this property may contain spaces or other special characters, and it should be properly encoded if provided in the connection URL. Spaces are considered to separate command-line arguments, unless escaped with a backslash (`\`); `\\` represents a literal backslash.

The `options` parameter this refers to is documented in [the PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNECT-OPTIONS):

> options
>
> Specifies command-line options to send to the server at connection start. For example, setting this to `-c geqo=off` sets the session's value of the `geqo` parameter to `off`. Spaces within this string are considered to separate command-line arguments, unless escaped with a backslash (`\`); write `\\` to represent a literal backslash. For a detailed discussion of the available options, consult [Chapter 19](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config.html).

So you should set the `options` parameter to

```
-cstatement_timeout=5000
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check this!